# In Spring Boot JPA, Not able to call an endpoint internally in code from another endpoint..autowiring not working..getting null pointer

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, annotations

Below endpoint is working from swagger

```
@Autowired
private EventService eventService;

@PostMapping(value = "/searchVolunteersByDistance")
public List<EventsVolunteerDistance> searchVolunteersByDistance(@RequestParam("eventId") long eventId,
            @RequestParam("distanceKm") int distanceInKm) throws Exception {
EventsAddress address5 = eventService.generalEventsRepository.getOne(eventId).getAddress();
```

But when I call it from

```
@PostMapping(value = "/searchVolunteersBySkillDistance")
public Map<Long, Long> searchVolunteersBySkillDistance(@RequestParam("eventId") long eventId,
            @RequestParam("mandatoryUserIds") List<Long> mandatoryUserIds,
            @RequestParam("mandatorySkillIds") List<Long> mandatorySkillIds,

            @RequestParam("unavailableUserIds") List<Long> unavailableUserIds,

            @RequestParam("distanceKm") int distanceInKm, @RequestParam("extraMerginPercent") int extraMerginPercent)
            throws Exception {
        Map<Long, Long> userSkillMap = new HashMap<Long, Long>();

        List<EventsVolunteerDistance> obj = new ArrayList<EventsVolunteerDistance>();
        locationSearchEngineController = new LocationSearchEngineController();
        obj = locationSearchEngineController.searchVolunteersByDistance(eventId, distanceInKm);
```

then I am getting null pointer exception at

```
EventsAddress address5 = eventService.generalEventsRepository.getOne(eventId).getAddress();
```

because eventService is null
why is autowiring not working?

Comment: because you are creating the object locationSearchEngineController manually, so spring doesn't inject the Autowired field. You should inject locationSearchEngineController in this case. A hint: one controller shouldn't call another one, you should share services instead.

Answer (score 2):

You have created a new instance of `LocationSearchEngineController` in your `searchVolunteersBySkillDistance` method. As you have created it yourself, the instance isn't managed by Spring and, therefore, has had any dependencies autowired into it. To avoid the problem, you should have Spring inject an instance rather than creating it yourself.

Unrelated to your problem with `EventService` being `null`, it is unusual for a method (`searchVolunteersBySkillDistance` in this case) on one controller to call a method on another controller. A more typically approach is to move any logic that you want to be shared between controllers into a service that is called by those controllers.